# Call to undefined function SendGrid\mb_convert_encoding() in /sendgrid-php/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php on line 729

Tags: php, email, sendgrid-api-v3

how I can solve this problem?

> Call to undefined function SendGrid\mb_convert_encoding() in /sendgrid-php/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php on line 729

this is my code

```
<?php

require("./sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "example@example.com");
$subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "example@example.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");

// Send message as html
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('my key');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

echo $response->statusCode();

print_r($response->headers());

echo $response->body();
```

Comment: i am not using composer

Comment: Any idea which line is 729?

Comment: You're probably not getting composer's autoload functionality.

Comment: there are two ways by using composer or without autoload is for composer but i am not using composer i include require("./sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php"); this file

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

You need to install the `mbstring` extension for PHP. If you're using Ubuntu, the command will probably be something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

You may need to adjust the package depending on your version of PHP. There are many resources online for installing `mbstring`.

---

Long answer:

When PHP encounters a function call inside a namespace, it will attempt to resolve that function inside the current namespace. As you would expect, the SendGrid library you're using doesn't define it's own `mb_convert_string()` so PHP will then attempt to check the global scope for a function called `mb_convert_string()`.

[`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) is part of the [`mbstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension. And because you don't have that extension installed, the function doesn't exist. PHP reports that a function doesn't exist in the SendGrid namespace because that's the first place it checked.

It's clear that the SendGrid developers are expecting the function to be in the global namespace. Install the extension and you should be good to go.

Comment: i am trying to send email from sendgrid i am on hosting how can i install this?

Comment: That's a long rabbit hole unfortunately. That's going to depend on your hosting. If you're on a shared-space hosting, you'll have to contact the vendor. If not... it depends on how PHP was setup. Most commonly you install it from your package manager. And different operating systems use different package managers. I wouldn't be able to do more than search Google myself. I'd use terms like `ubuntu install php mbsting` or `centos install php mbstring` or `debian install mbstring` or `archlinux install mbstring`, you get the idea?